# selenium tests failing with phantomjs again after fixing also

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, teamcity

I am not sure what all information will be required for this question to be answered but still its better to ask.

My selenium tests were failing due to page not loading and I had fixed this issue by adding ssl protocol in the capabilities. My branch was all green and after merging to parent everything was fine.
One of the dev forked from parent after and he is facing with the same error messages and failures that I had fixed earlier.
Now I don't know how to approach to this? Is this something related to his branch (maybe not merged properly) ??
Any pointers or questions can be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: There's too little information and I highly doubt that adding all necessary information will result in a short enough question that is useful. I guess this question is not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ArtjomB.I know the info is less ...I don't know what all info is to be included in this question....help me by asking me questions so that I can give more info.